# Is there any option in SharePoint 2013 Office 365 to do Full Crawl or Incremental Crawl or Continuous Crawl?

Tags: enterprise-search, managed-property, content-search-web-part

Is there any option in SharePoint 2013 Office 365 to do Full Crawl or Incremental Crawl or Continuous Crawl as On-premises SharePoint 2013.

If there is no option to do so ?? then what is the best way to see the results quickly when i created Managed Property and Map a crawl property to it.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot set the crawl in O365.  It is set to do a continuous crawl, and should take ~15 minutes for results to show in search results.  However, in times of heavy use, that can increase to hours.  This link provides more information: http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/10/waiting-for-search-crawl-in-office-365.html

Answer (score 3):

No it is not possible, but you can request a reindexing on site level. See the following quote:

> When you have changed a managed property, or when you have changed the mapping of crawled and managed properties, the site must be re-crawled before your changes will be reflected in the search index. Because your changes are made in the search schema, and not to the actual site, the crawler will not automatically re-index the site. To make sure that your changes are crawled and fully re-indexed, you must request a re-indexing of the site. The site content will be re-crawled and re-indexed so that you can start using the managed properties in queries, query rules and display templates.

To request a reindexing:

1. On the site, click Settings > Site Settings.
2. Under Search, click Search and offline availability.
3. In the Reindex site section, click Reindex site.
4. A warning appears, click Reindex site again to confirm. The content will be re-indexed during the next scheduled crawl.

All from http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/manually-request-crawling-and-re-indexing-of-a-site-a-library-or-a-list-HA104052395.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This script comes close to a full crawl: http://techmikael.blogspot.de/2014/02/how-to-trigger-full-re-index-in.html?m=1

Comment: Please add more details to this so it will be an answer. Right now it feels more like a comment to one of the existing answers or the question itself.